# Undefined index: DLL

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['first']) && isset($_POST['second']) && isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['DDL'] == "+")
{
    $equals = $_POST['first'] + $_POST['second'];
}
if (isset($_POST['first']) && isset($_POST['second']) && isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['DDL'] == "-")
{
    $equals = $_POST['first'] - $_POST['second'];
}
if (isset($_POST['first']) && isset($_POST['second']) && isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['DDL'] == "*")
{
    $equals = $_POST['first'] * $_POST['second'];
}
if (isset($_POST['first']) && isset($_POST['second']) && isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['DDL'] == "/")
{
    $equals = $_POST['first'] / $_POST['second'];
}

print $_POST['DDL']; // THIS IS THE LINE THAT RESULTS IN THE ERROR! WHY?

?>

<html>
<body>

<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="first">

<select name="DDL">
<option value="+" selected="selected">+</option>
<option value="-">-</option>b
<option value="*">*</option>
<option value="/">/</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="second">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Equals">
<input type="text" name="equals" value="<?php if (!empty($equals)) print($equals) ?>">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The previous code results in the following error when accessing the index.php file BEFORE SUBMITTING THE FORM:

[image: a busy cat]

The php code "print $_POST['DDL'];" is causing the error.

Why is this happening?
I've already chosen a default value by using "+"...

Comment: So it results in the undefined index after you post the form?

Comment: The error disappears after I post the form and prints out the desired result.

Comment: `$_POST["DDL"]` will not be present before the form is posted. That's how forms work. You could use `isset()` like you do in the code above to prevent the error from showing

Comment: Is it impossible to print out the default value of the Drop Down List before submitting a form then?

Comment: yes, because it is not known to your script. You would have to define the default value in a PHP variable, show it, and then use that PHP variable to populate the select field. (Or just define the default value a second time in PHP, which is much easier but creates two places you need to edit if you want to change it later.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first visit the page, you don't have any post data. 
This fires the exception you're getting.

you should check the $_POST value / existence before processing the form data.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thank you!  
But is it impossible to print out the default value of the Drop Down List before submitting a form then?

Comment: yes. you can't grab the default value of the dropdown-list before you post it using php.

Comment: Or, if you want to do this server side, you can check if you've got post data, and if not, you can print out or store the intended default value in a variable.